# Generate SQL CE database from EF Code-First DbContext class

Tags: .net, entity-framework, sql-server-ce, code-first, ef-code-first

I've defined a set of classes in the style of Entity Framework Code-First conventions and annotated the class properties with System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations attributes.

Now I want to generate a SQL Server Compact Edition (SCSE) (4.0) database from this code.

What code is needed to do this and what assemblies need to be imported?

So far I've imported the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v4.0\Desktop{System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll,System.Data.SqlServerCe.Entity\System.Data.SqlServerCe.Entity.dll} dll files.

Any pointers appreciated. Articles and whatnot.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found the solution. The critical thing is this line of code:

```
DbDatabase.DefaultConnectionFactory = new 
                      SqlCeConnectionFactory("System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0");
```

Here's a full sample:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Proto
{
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Database;
    using System.Data.SqlServerCe;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DbDatabase.DefaultConnectionFactory = new 
                        SqlCeConnectionFactory("System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0");
            DbDatabase.SetInitializer(
                         new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ProtoCatalog>()
                  );

            using (var db = new ProtoCatalog())
            {
                var user = new User
                {
                    Name = "bob",
                    Password = "123",
                    Creation = DateTime.Now,
                    PrimaryEmailAddress = "bob@example.com"
                };

                db.Users.Add(user);

                db.SaveChanges();

                Console.ReadKey();
            }
       }
    }

    public class ProtoCatalog : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    }

    public class User
    {
        [Key, StringLength(50)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required, StringLength(100)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Required, StringLength(320)]
        public string PrimaryEmailAddress { get; set; }

        [StringLength(320)]
        public string SecondaryEmailAddress { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime Creation { get; set; }

        public bool Active { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The API will probably change between EF Code-First CTP 5 and RTM though, but this is how it's done now.

I've made a small [blog post](http://xosfaere.wordpress.com/2011/01/30/entity-framework-code-first-development-with-sql-ce-4-0/) about it.

Answer (score 2):

See this blog and links in the same (for example the ScottGu article): http://erikej.blogspot.com/2011/01/sql-server-compact-40-released.html

Comment: Thanks. I'll check those out.

Answer (score 2):

The best way I found was to install NuGet and play with the EF CodeFirst and SQL CE 4 packages, there is also a sample you can install from NuGet that has code examples for all the db creation strategies.
You would do something like:

```
install-package EFCodeFirst.SqlServerCompact
install-package EFCodeFirst.Sample
```

In the root of your project directory should be a file called "AppStart_SQLCEEntityFramework.cs" refer to that for examples.

Comment: Thanks! I just have Visual C# Express installed at home but that may change.

Answer (score 2):

Another way of providing the DefaultConnectionProvider is by adding it in app.config.

```
<entityFramework>
  <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
    <parameters>
      <parameter value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
    </parameters>
  </defaultConnectionFactory>
</entityFramework>
```