# WinForms Entity Framework Code-First Support

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, entity-framework-4

Does Winforms support **`Code-First`** Entity Framework. I know ASP.net MVC support it, but how about Winforms?

I create connection string in app.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name ="Transaction" connectionString="DataSource=|DataDirectory|Transaction.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

I also create Transaction class with all the fields, and Transaction DbContext, but when I compile, it does not create the sdf file automatically.

Thank you.

**UPDATE** I added this two lines, but is still not working:

```
Database.DefaultConnectionFactory = new SqlCeConnectionFactory("System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0");
            Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<EmvTransactions>());
```

It gives me this error:

```
> An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception
> for details.
```

Comment: I think here is your answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838217/generate-sql-ce-database-from-ef-code-first-dbcontext-class

Comment: You need to call an Initialize and install a DropDatabaseifChanged thing. @Giedrius - normally from App_Start() in MVC.

Comment: @Henk Holterman I am not using ASP.net MVC, I am using Winforms.

Comment: Then you need to call it somewhere else. I was responding to an older comment.

Comment: And what is the inner exception?

Comment: @Slauma How can I track the inner exception.

Comment: `InnerException` is a property of the outer the exception you have shown in your question. Just drill into the exception details in the debugger.

Comment: I have solved the problem, tq all.

Comment: Maybe you could write your solution as answer (or delete the question).